# unsubscribe is not a function on an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, unsubscribe

I'm making a drag and drop application and I have created an observable to the mouse position, that repositions my `drag-object`.

```
mouseMove$: any;

constructor(){
  this.mouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
    .do((mouseevent: MouseEvent) => {
      if (document.getElementById("drag-object")){
        document.getElementById("drag-object").style.left = (mouseevent.clientX) + 'px';
        document.getElementById("drag-object").style.top = (mouseevent.clientY) + 'px';
      }
  });
```

With this implementation I have no problem subscribing in this way:

```
this.mouseMove$.subscribe();
```

however I cannot seem to unsubscribe by either:

```
this.mouseMove$.unsubscribe();
```

or

```
this.mouseMove$.dispose();
```

in either case I get the following type of error:

> TypeError: this.mouseMove$.unsubscribe is not a function ...

I'm not sure if this has to do with the `mouseMove$` type of `any`, but setting the type as `Observable` and `Observable<MouseEvent>` did not work. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're probably using a newer version of RxJS, where there has been an API change where `Observable.subscribe` returns a `Disposable`, from which you call `.unsubscribe` now (`dispose` became `unsubscribe` in RxJS5). Unfortunately there are still lots of old tutorials and blog posts out there doing it "the old way", resulting in this confusion.

Thus, your code should be

```
let disposeMe = this.mouseMove$.subscribe();
```

and, after you're done

```
disposeMe.unsubscribe();
```

For a full list of API changes from Version 4 to 5, check [this file](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Answer (score 4):

make sure your `this.mouseMove$` is an observable first:

```
if (this.mouseMove$ !== undefined) {
  this.mouseMove$.unsubscribe();
}
```

probably in your case, you unsubscribe before `this.mouseMove$` has not been assigned any value yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.getValue= this.ntUser.salesEnquiry()
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
    // some action
          this.getdataapi.unsubscribe();
        },
        (error) => {
          // some action
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Please explain the reason why the OP was facing the issue and how your answer resolves it.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [brianflove.com](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/).

By setting mouseMove$: ISubscription, should take care of the issue.

Comment: can you modify answer please with core description?

Comment: Instead of using "mouseMove$: any", declare the data type to ISubscription, will remove the error you are seeing.