# Uncaught TypeError shown in Karma when unit testing in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Suppose i have a service named **testService** with a function **getData** in it. Also i have a component ( say **A** ) into which the service is injected.

```
export class A implements OnInit,OnDestroy{
    saveObj;

    constructor(public service:testService){

    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      if(this.saveObj) this.saveObj.unsubscribe();
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.saveObj = this.service.getData.subscribe(res => {
            this.func(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error Occured");
            this.saveObj.unsubscribe();
        });
    }

    private func(result: any){
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Now i am doing ***unit testing*** for this component. The problem is in some cases , it throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.saveObj.unsubscribe is not a function thrown
```

Code snippet of spec.ts:

```
// testServiceStub is just a mock of testService. 

beforeEach(async(()=>{
    testServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getData']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations : [A],
        schemas : [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        providers : [
            { provide : testService, useValue: testServiceStub }
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}))

beforeEach(async(()=>{
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(A);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
}))

it('checks whether error is handled or not',()=>{
    spyOn(console,'log');
    testServiceStub.getData.and.returnValue(throwError({status:404})); 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled(); // shows the TypeError
})


it('checks whether value is handled or not',()=>{
    testServiceStub.getData.and.returnValue(of(mockData)); // some mock data
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.func).toHaveBeenCalled();  // also shows the TypeError
})
```

I also referred this link [unsubscribe is not a function on an observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191077/unsubscribe-is-not-a-function-on-an-observable) . But the problem is it also works in some cases and no error is shown.

Please help me figure out the reason and possible scenarios.

UPD: Added onDestroy lifecycle hook

Comment: Please do null check before you unsubscribe the subscriptions. And also this can be done within `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle method

Comment: Hello Amit, i added it still the error remains. Can you tell me why this error comes at all? and also when it would work without fail?

Comment: @RahulChowdhury I already gave an answer about Subscriptions and how to properly unsubscribe from observables on destroy. Please try my explained approach with Subject and takeUntil here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355066/how-to-implement-behavior-subject-using-service-in-angular-8/57355485#57355485

Comment: Tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury As mentioned in the above comment, you are trying to access the subscription variable before it is assigned with the `Subscription` object. For the first time, it would give you error, hence it is recommended to add null check. In your case it safe to kill the subscriptions in `ngOnDestroy` hook.

Comment: Also you should be adding null check within error callback if you still wish to use that. But I would say it is not required to unsubscribe within error callback.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more "you are trying to access the subscription variable before it is assigned with the Subscription object".  Also check if my final code is the way you wanted it or not? Also please help me to improve my answer if there are any flaws.

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: Yes it is. But I wanted to know what @Amit meant by that line... that's all.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury I have added a small [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sub-destroy-within-self?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Hope that should clear your doubts. Check the console logs where the first sub is undefined.

Comment: Yes thank you. It cleared what you said. Mind checking the code which i wrote in the answer? is it fine?

Comment: Hello @Amit, can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095430/callback-and-testing-highcharts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Amit Chigadani

```
export class A implements OnInit,OnDestroy{
    saveObj: Subscription ;

    constructor(public service:testService){

    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      if(this.saveObj) 
             this.saveObj.unsubscribe();
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.saveObj = this.service.getData.subscribe(res => {
            this.func(res);
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error Occured");
        });
    }

    private func(result: any){
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nasty. This field is declared as a `Subscription`, **not** a `Subscription | undefined`, yet it is not initialized in the constructor, so it must be undefined for some period of time after this object is created. We should be able to catch these errors at compile time, but for some reason the TypeScript compiler doesn't catch this even with strict mode turned on.